# Laravel Where In Queries

Tags: database, laravel

I need to get the data where its not in another table, but mine isnt working..

this is my first table query

```
$hospDriver=DB::table('hospital_drivers')
->select('DriverID')
->get();
```

and this is for the notin

```
$checkDriverAvail = DB::table('emergencyorders_temp')
->select('DriverID')
->get();
```

This is the main one

```
$driverwithin = Driver::
                    select(array(
                        'drivers.DriverID',
                        'drivers.DriverName',
                        'drivers.DriverPhone',
                        'ambulance_types.TypeName',
                        'ambulances.PoliceNo',
                        'driverlocation.Latitude',
                        'driverlocation.Longitude',
                        'driverlocation.DriverActive',
                        DB::raw($haversine . ' as distance')))
                     ->leftjoin('driverlocation','driverlocation.DriverID','=','drivers.DriverID')
                     ->leftjoin('ambulances','ambulances.AmbulanceID','=','driverlocation.AmbulanceID')
                     ->leftjoin('ambulance_types','ambulances.AmbulanceTypeID','=','ambulance_types.AmbulanceTypeID')
                     ->leftjoin('ambulance_drivers','ambulance_drivers.DriverID','=','drivers.DriverID')
->where('driverlocation.DriverActive', 1)
->whereIn('drivers.DriverID',array([$hospDriver]))
->whereNotIn('drivers.DriverID', array([$checkDriverAvail]))
->having('distance', '<=', 10)
->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
->get();
```

and this is my error

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

where am I wrong? thanks!

Comment: The error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` usually occurs when you try to do an (implicit) string cast onto an object (in this case a "stdObject" which is the PHP "Default" Class). Can u point to the line the error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lavarel Query Builder `get` does return an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP `stdClass` object.

So your vars `$hospDriver` and `$checkDriverAvail` are objects. The functions `whereIn` and `whereNotIn` require an array of Integers (e.g. `->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])` to work.

You need to iterate trough the Collections in `$hospDriver` and `$checkDriverAvail` and create integer arrays.

```
$hospDriverIds=array();
$checkDriverAvailIds=array();

foreach($hospDriver as $driver)
    $hospDriverIds[]=$driver->ID;

foreach($checkDriverAvail as $availDriver)
    $checkDriverAvailIds[]=$availDriver->ID;
```

Now you can use those ID Arrays for your conditions. Change

```
->whereIn('drivers.DriverID',array([$hospDriver]))
->whereNotIn('drivers.DriverID', array([$checkDriverAvail]))`
```

to

```
->whereIn('drivers.DriverID', $hospDriverIds)
->whereNotIn('drivers.DriverID', $checkDriverAvailIds)
```

Now your array given into `whereIn` and `whereNotIn` contain integers as the implementation requires.

More info (and detailed descriptions) can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Comment: it works, but the data came out twice, should i distinct the query?

Comment: @Cookie: Yes, adding the `DISTINCT` keyword to `drivers.DriverID` (should look like this: `DISTINCT drivers.DriverID`) will make every DriverID only appear once in your resultset. If my answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted answer (click the checkmark below the vote icons).

Comment: yeah i was waiting for this reply.. thank you so much for your info!